# WordPress Block Registration ES6 /ESNext Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have been looking everywhere to see why my code will not work.  I am trying to create a WordPress Gutenberg Block using the following code.  I have tested 3 versions of code from different websites and have not been able to figure out why it fails on `<div className={className}>`

PHP - functions.php

```
function register_block_editor_assets() {
  $dependencies = array(
    'wp-blocks',    // Provides useful functions and components for extending the editor
    'wp-i18n',      // Provides localization functions
    'wp-element',   // Provides React.Component
    'wp-components' // Provides many prebuilt components and controls
  );
  wp_register_script( 'my-block-editor', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/testing2.js', $dependencies );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_block_editor_assets' );

function register_block_assets() {
  wp_register_script( 'my-block', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/testing2.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_block_assets' );
```

JS - testing2.js

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const {
    RichText,
    BlockControls,
    AlignmentToolbar,
} = wp.editor;
registerBlockType( 'example/example-block', {
  title = __('Example Block', 'example'),
  icon = 'screenoptions',
  category = 'common',
  attributes = {
    content: { // Parsed from HTML selector
      source: 'children',
      selector: 'p',
      type: 'array'
    },
    textColor: { // Serialized by default
      type: 'string'
    },
    isPinned: { // Pulled from REST API
      type: 'boolean',
      source: 'meta',
      meta: 'example_is_pinned'
    }
  },
  edit = ({ attributes, setAttributes, className, isSelected }) => {
      const {
        content
      } = attributes
      return (
        <div className={className}>
          <RichText
            className="example-content"
            value={content}
            onChange={(content) =>setAttributes({ content })} />
        </div>
      )
  }),
  save = ({ attributes }) {
      const {
        content
      } = attributes
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{content}</p>
        </div>
      ) 
  })
};
```

Comment: Are you transpiling the JSX using babel? Might explain why you're getting a syntax error for HTML. The other option would be to not use JSX and use plain Javascript: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Comment: @james, did you get answer on this ? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your js file.

Try this code

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const {
    RichText,
    BlockControls,
    AlignmentToolbar,
} = wp.editor;
registerBlockType( 'example/example-block', {
    title :__('Example Block', 'example'),
    icon : 'screenoptions',
    category : 'common',
    attributes : {
        content: { // Parsed from HTML selector
            source: 'children',
            selector: 'p',
            type: 'array'
        },
        textColor: { // Serialized by default
            type: 'string'
        },
        isPinned: { // Pulled from REST API
            type: 'boolean',
            source: 'meta',
            meta: 'example_is_pinned'
        }
    },
    edit(props){
        const {attributes, setAttributes, className} = props;
            const {
                content
            } = attributes
            return (
                <div className={className}>
                    <RichText
                        className="example-content"
                        value={content}
                        onChange={(content) =>setAttributes({ content })} />
                </div>
            )
        },
    save(props){
    const {attributes} = props;
    const {
        content
    } = attributes
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{content}</p>
        </div>
    )
} });
```

Comment: Wordpress can't render jsx directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to transpile jsx and react components into regular javascript syntax, that's why you get that error. You can use a transpiler like babel.

JSX is a language extension that requires transpilation. You can read more about it from its spec: https://github.com/facebook/jsx

If you are not familiar at all, please check these links:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html